# how can I show all data in a mail using for each in php?

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I prepared the HTML-code to send a mail with this PHP-script:

```
public function setData ($usuarios){ 

            foreach($usuarios as $sKey=>$oValue){
              $htmlmail = file_get_contents('helpers/mailAvisoSinTareasReg/contenido.html');
              $htmlReplace = str_replace("<tbody><tr><td>firstname</td></tr></tbody>",$oValue['nombre_usuario'],$htmlmail);  
              $this->oPhpMailer->msgHTML($htmlReplace); 
            }

            $this->sendMail();
            }
```

The file `helpers/mailAvisoSinTareasReg/contenido.html` contains next code in HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Nombre</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody><tr><td>firstname</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

`$usuarios` contains next array:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_usuario] => 6
            [nombre_usuario] => Daniel
            [apellido_usuario] => Reyes
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id_usuario] => 7
        [nombre_usuario] => Maria
        [apellido_usuario] => Cecilia
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id_usuario] => 8
        [nombre_usuario] => Nicolas
        [apellido_usuario] => Contreras
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id_usuario] => 9
        [nombre_usuario] => Karel
        [apellido_usuario] => Jouannet
    )

)
```

Finally I need to show all the `[nombre_usuario]` in the mail:

In fact the mail content is next:

[image]

However, I need show Daniel, Maria, Nicolas and Karel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dynamically create rows of names. Read content of file. And replace the name section with dynamically created html data.

```
      public function setData ($usuarios){ 
    $html = '';  //local variable for dynamic html
     $htmlmail = file_get_contents('helpers/mailAvisoSinTareasReg/contenido.html'); //read the contents
    foreach($usuarios as $sKey=>$oValue){
        $$html .= '<tbody><tr><td>'.$oValue['nombre_usuario'].'</td></tr></tbody>';  //add every name row
        }
        $htmlReplace = str_replace("<tbody><tr><td>firstname</td></tr></tbody>",$html,$htmlmail);  //replace name row with dynamic data
    $this->oPhpMailer->msgHTML($htmlReplace); //add it to mailer
    $this->sendMail();
}
```

Comment: Hi ty but i need use the content from file_get_contents

Comment: Edited now. Check it.@Jeanbf

Comment: sorry but how can i add other column?

Comment: '<tbody><tr><td>'.$oValue['nombre_usuario'].'</td><td>'.$oValue['new value/column'].'</td></tr></tbody>';